# How to make a button only visible under certain condition(the condition increase everytime one clicks the button?)

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a Javascript game, where I would like a button (class = "build") to only be visible under certain conditions, and the condition would increase every time after one click the button.

To increase the number by 1, click the "gather" button. To make it more effective, click the "build" button to automatically increase the number by 0.1 per second. That is what's happening in the code below.

But I would like the "build" button to be only visible after the number reached 10. The "build" button would decrease the current number by 50% when one clicks it so that it would become invisible after being clicked.

The second time, the "build" button would only be visible when the number reached 12. Click it, the number decreases 50%, the "build" button disappears. The third time the button would become visible when the number reached 14 (so it's +2 every time"), click it, the number decreases 50%, the "build" button disappears and it goes on and on.

Is there any way for this to work? Thanks!

```
let btn1 = document.querySelector(".btn1");
let btn2 = document.querySelector(".btn2");
let num = document.getElementById("num");
let increment = 0;

function toGather(){
num.innerHTML++;
}

btn1.addEventListener("click",toGather)

function toBuild() {
increment+=.1

if (increment == .1){
  setInterval(() => {
    num.innerHTML =parseFloat(parseInt((parseFloat(num.innerHTML)+.05+increment)*10)/10);
    
    
  }, 1000)} else num.innerHTML =parseFloat(parseInt((parseFloat(num.innerHTML)+.05+increment)*10)/10);
}

btn2.addEventListener("click",toBuild);
```

```
<span id="num">0</span>
<button class="btn1">Gather</button>
<button class="btn2">Build</button>
```

Comment: You've described your requirements, but you haven't told us what problem you've encountered, nor have you explained at what point in your code you're having that problem.  Please edit your question and clarify exactly where in your code you aren't getting the results you expect, and what problem is occurring.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience! I have edited the post now.

Comment: You should add your condition (being more than 10) in the interval, right before or after changing innerHTML. And that's it. Any time you change the number, you must check.

Answer (score 0):

```js
if ()
document.querySelector('.btn2').classList.add('.build')
else if ()
document.querySelector('.btn2').classList.remove('.build')
```

You put a display none on the class btn2 and a display block for the class build, you add the condition between the brackets of my code and it should be good